# Hibernate InvocationTargetException by only SELECT when called from WebApp. Works for INSERT (persist)

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, netbeans

Im trying to select 1 user from this code:

```
   public static User getUserById(Long id) {
        try {
            String query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.id =  " + id;
//bbddgestor is a class that provides utilites to build SessionFactory and configure Hibernate.            
            Session sesion = bbddgestor.SessionFactory.getSession().getCurrentSession();
            sesion.beginTransaction();
            Query sentence = sesion.createQuery(query);
            List<User> users = sentence.getResultList();
            sesion.getTransaction().commit();
            return users.get(0);
        } catch (Exception excp) {
    ...
            return fakeUser;
        }

    }
```

I have also a check method to insert a new User into my DB:

```
public static void createUserFake (User userPar){
    //This method just creates a valid user. In this case, we dont use userPar, we create and persist one directly, just to check.
    User user = main.Main.createFakeUser();
    Session sesion = bbddgestor.SessionFactory.getSession().getCurrentSession();
    sesion.beginTransaction();
    user.setLog("CREATED");
    sesion.persist(user);
    sesion.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

I call both methods from a JSP script, as you can see here. As you can see, I call first the creator method, and then the select one in order to obtain the user with ID = 1:

```
<%@ page import="bbddgestor.BBDDController" %>
<%@ page import="webtest.User" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%
    try {
        BBDDController.createUserFake(null);
        User user = BBDDController.getUserById(1L);
        out.print(user.getJSONObj()); //Ignore this line, the error is on the previous line
    } catch (Exception excp) {
        //Ignore this exception handling
        out.println("Error JSON: " + excp);
        out.println("Cause: " + excp.getCause().getMessage());
    }

%>
```

Both methods are coded in the same class, both static. This class is part of utilities library coded in a separate project. JSP is part of a WebApp project that uses the mentioned project as part of its libraries.

Hibernate configuration code is part of a class SessionFactory. Variable sessionFactory is a Factory reusable in any part of code:

```
    public class SessionFactory {

    //Inicializes session
    static {
        createSession();
    }

    static org.hibernate.SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static void createSession() {
...
         Configuration configurationAux = new Configuration();
                    //configurationAux.configure();
                    configurationAux.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    configurationAux.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pruebas?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull");
                    configurationAux.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "root");
                    configurationAux.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "toor");
                    configurationAux.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
                    configurationAux.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
                    configurationAux.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
                    configurationAux.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");

                    try {
                        configurationAux
                                .addAnnotatedClass(webtest.Category.class)
                                .addAnnotatedClass(webtest.Question.class)
                                .addAnnotatedClass(webtest.Test.class)
                                .addAnnotatedClass(webtest.User.class)
                                .addAnnotatedClass(webtest.Answer.class)
                                .addAnnotatedClass(webtest.TryTest.class)
                                .addAnnotatedClass(webtest.TupleQuestion.class)
                                .addAnnotatedClass(webtest.TupleToAnswer.class);

                        configuration = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                                .applySettings(configurationAux.getProperties())
                                .build();
                        SessionFactory.sessionFactory = configurationAux.buildSessionFactory(configuration);
                        return;
                        //Done this exception.
                    } catch (HibernateException excpi) {
    ...
           }
```

Well then, the problem:

> - Second method (**createUserFake**) works fine no matter where you call it from. If you call from the JSP shown, it works. If you call it
>     from a desktop library, it works fine as well.
> - First method (**getUserById**) only works from a desktop or console app. When I call it from JSP script throws an
>     InvocationTargetException, even if createUserFake(null) has worked
>     fine before in the same JSP script.

What should I be doing wrong?

Comment: First of all; the query should be like this: `String query = "SELECT * FROM User u WHERE u.id =  " + id;`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Select sentence is written in Hibernate SQL, so it works fine. It works also from a command line app.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm

Comment: Hi, ty for your reply. You can consult Hibernate documentation query here:
[link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#query-api)

xmple from the documentation:
    `@NamedQuery(
     ...
        query = "select p from Person p where name = :name"`

Or:
`Query query = entityManager.createQuery(
    "select p " +
    "from Person p " +
    "where p.name like :name"
);`
Anyway, from a command line or desktop application Hibernate SQL worked fine (not a Syntax error). Why do you think it fails if called from JSP?
Thank you, Taheri.

Comment: Example of query:
[link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#jpql-api)
So i think SQL should be fine. Maybe the exception comes from JSP?
Thank you Taheri.

Comment: I just guessed it, regarding your question, could you print the stacktrace in the low level exceptions and post them here. `InvocationTargetException` just says there is and exception throwed somewhere.